# Как не соединять в одну цепочку письма от разных получателей , работая в gmail

Tags: php, email, sendmail, gmail

Добрый день.
Делаю рассылку по емейлам, перебирая их в цикле.

```
foreach ($emails as $value) {
  $subject = "=?utf-8?b?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?="; 
  mail($value, $subject, $send_mails, $headers); 
}
```

Но проблема в том, что если ответит несколько получателей, то гугл.почта сформирует одну цепочку писем. 
Как сделать чтобы ответы от разных получателей были в разных цепочках, при этом тема сообщения была одинаковая? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. вы отправляете индивидуальные письма каждому получателю, то остается просто добавить к теме письма (в конце переменной $subject) какую-либо информацию из данных о получателе: его email, ID в базе, фамилию и т.п.